# How to fetch data from one field of a schema to another new field of a schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mlab

I have a production app running with about 400+ customers, below are two schema present,

```
var CustomerSchema = new Schema{
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    phone:{
        type: Number
    },
    vehicleNo:{
        type: String
    }
}

var serviceSchema = new Schema{
    customer:{
        type: Schema.Type.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    }
    vehicleType:{
        type: String //Eg: car or bike
    },
    servicePlace:{
        type: Number
    },
    nextServiceDate:{
        type: Date
    }
}
```

I made a mistake, i actually need the vehicleType in serviceSchema to be present in CustomerSchema.

And the CustomerSchema should look like this,

```
var CustomerSchema = new Schema{
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    phone:{
        type: Number
    },
    vehicleNo:{
        type: String
    },
    vehicleType:{
        type: String //Eg: car or bike
    }
}
```

Now, how do can i map or bring all the existing users vehicle type to customerSchema. And the further data will be collected as per the new customerSchema.

i am a beginner and i really need help badly since it is in production.

Comment: how would you know which vehicle belongs to which type ?

Comment: Sorry about that i have edited my question now, i have a customer id in service schema